# MATLAB double inequality

Tags: matlab, inequality

I am having some trouble understand why this is wrong

```
if x<=-1
elseif pwres=1
elseif -1<x<=1
   pwres=x.^2
else
   pwres=x.^3 
end
```

I have been told not to write -1 in line #3.
Does MATLAB not support double inequality?
Also is it supposed to be x.^2 or x^2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attempt `-1<x<=1`, MATLAB first calculates `-1<x` and returns 0 or 1 depending on the result. The 0 or 1 you end up with then gets compared to `1` using the `<=` operation, which would always return 1.

Effectively, you'd end up with a result of 1 for any value of `x`.